Relation between five aggregates and four establishments of mindfulness?
I have been wondering what the connection between the five aggregates and the four establishments are. Below i give the translations into English that i've found when reading Bhikkhu Bodhi (BB) and Thich Nhat Hanh (TNH)
Five aggregates:

Form
Feelings
Perceptions
Volitional formations (BB); Mental Formations (TNH)
Consciousness

Four establishments of mindfulness:

Body
Feelings
Mind, States of Mind (BB); Mind, Mental Formations (TNH)
Phenomena (BB); Objects of mind (TNH)

How can i think about the connection between these lists?
More specifically:

Why is "perceptions" not included in the establishments of mindfulness?
What's the difference between "form" and "body"?
Are "Volitional formations (BB); Mental Formations (TNH)" and "Mind, States of Mind (BB); Mind, Mental Formations (TNH)" the same thing?
What's the relation between "Consciousness" and "Phenomena (BB); Objects of mind (TNH)"?


1st aggregate = rupa = form or materiality = earth, wind, fire, water (SN 12.2; AN 9.15; SN 12.61). MN 62 contains detailed description. Also SN 22.79.
1st satipatthana = kaya = 'group' = 'sabba-kaya' = 'all groups' = all of the five aggregates. For example, experiencing how the state of the mind directly affects/influences the state of the breathing & the state of the physical body = kaya satipatthana. The Patisambiddhmagga says 'sabba-kaya' = nama-kaya (mental group) & rupa-kaya (physical group). The terms 'nama-kaya' & 'rupa-kaya' are also found in DN 15. Unfortunately, every modern monk is wrong about 'sabba-kaya' or 'kaya satipatthana'. Buddhadasa was close but was also wrong. Only DD and Patisambiddhmagga.

Body: there are two bodies: the mental body and the material body. What is the mental body? Feeling, perception, volition, contact,
attention, and mentality are the mental body, and also what are called
cognizance formations: these are the mental body.
What is the material body? The four great entities [elements] and the materiality
derived by clinging from the four great entities, in-breath and
out-breath and the sign for anchoring [mindfulness], and also what are
called body formations: this is the material body.
How is he acquainted with these bodies? When he understands unification of cognizance and non-distraction through long in-breaths, his mindfulness is established (founded). By means of that mindfulness and that knowledge he is acquainted with those bodies. When he understands unification of cognizance and non-distraction through long out-breaths, … through short in-breaths, … through short out-breaths, his mindfulness is established (founded). By means of that mindfulness and that knowledge he is acquainted with those bodies.
Patisambiddhmagga

Perception is not included in satipatthana because perception is too subtle to be a pervasive object of contemplation. Feeling in satipatthana does not refer to momentary feelings arising from sense contact but, instead, refers to relatively long enduring feelings of rapture & happiness arising from calming the breathing (MN 118). While MN 10 is a fake sutta, enduring painful feelings can also be an object of satipatthana however, unless one is stream-enterer, there will probably be too much 'self' involved in the attempted contemplation of painful feelings. The point of satipatthana is to discern feelings as being 'not-self' or 'alien' ('parato'). This generally can only occur when breathing & thought have been calmed away and only pervasive rapture & happiness remain.
The 4th aggregate is mental formations. The translation 'volitional formations' is based on one sutta (SN 22.56) and is too limited. Mental formations are very broad & diverse in variety (such as underlying tendencies, fermentations, cravings, intentions, thoughts, mental images, extended thinking, views, etc). The translation 'volitional formations" is far too limited and an obsession of BB who is obsessed with reincarnation (similar to Sujato's kooky 'choices') and the false view that sankhara in Dependent Origination refers to volitional formations (when it does not; it refers to SN 41.6). A better definition of the 4th aggregate is found in SN 22.79 translated properly by Thanissaro.

"And why do you call them 'fabrications'? Because they fabricate fabricated things, thus they are called 'fabrications.' What do they fabricate as a fabricated thing? For the sake of form-ness, they fabricate form as a fabricated thing. For the sake of feeling-ness, they fabricate feeling as a fabricated thing. For the sake of perception-hood... For the sake of fabrication-hood... For the sake of consciousness-hood, they fabricate consciousness as a fabricated thing. Because they fabricate fabricated things, they are called fabrications.
SN 22.79

The 3rd satipatthana is 'citta'. 'Citta' refers to mind with or without defilements (kilesa; AN 1.49; greed, hatred & delusion) rather than explicity to thinking (vitakka). To translate 'citta' as 'mental formations' is too broad & wrong. BB's 'mental states' is better. To practice citta satipatthana fully, there must be no thoughts in the mind & the direct experience of defilement elements, so those defilements elements are clearly discerned as 'not-self' & 'alien'; as mere elements. If there is thinking occurring, there is probably self-views still dominating the mind; which is not effective citta satipatthana.
In addition, citta satipatthana includes experiencing the liberated mind, which includes a mind without any salient mental formations, therefore to equate citta satipatthana with mental formations is not accurate.
The 4th satipatthana is 'Dhamma Principles' or 'Truth'. Both BB & TNH are wrong here. Buddhadasa provided a good explanation. Sujato also correctly translates as 'principles'.

Form is the four great elements that the physical universe is made of, including the body. Since we naturally take the body to be our self, that's what they would normally have us examine, but you can certainly look at other things to try to see how they too are empty of essence/self, as well as being transient and therefore dukkha.

Feeling, perception, volition, contact and attention — these are called mentality. The four great elements and the material form derived from the four great elements — these are called materiality. So this mentality and this materiality are what is called mentality-materiality. With the arising of consciousness there is the arising of mentality-materiality. With the cessation of consciousness there is the cessation of mentality-materiality. -MN 9

Some teachings have you examine the aggregates down to the tiniest part, and it helps to have the separate categories, but they can also be put more simply as just mind and body, "name" and form, and anything you can be aware of, including perception, is a mental object, in which you can look for impermanence, dukkha, and selflessness. Perception is actually included in the fourth foundation in the Satipatthana Sutta:

How, monks, does a monk live contemplating mental objects in the mental objects of the five aggregates of clinging? Herein, monks, a monk thinks, ... "Thus is perception; thus is the arising of perception; and thus is the disappearance of perception." ...
...a monk knows the eye and visual forms and the fetter that arises dependent on both (the eye and forms); he knows how the arising of the non-arisen fetter comes to be; he knows how the abandoning of the arisen fetter comes to be; and he knows how the non-arising in the future of the abandoned fetter comes to be.
He knows the ear and sounds... the nose and smells... the tongue and flavors... the body and tactual objects... the mind and mental objects, and the fetter that arises dependent on both; he knows how the arising of the non-arisen fetter comes to be; he knows how the abandoning of the arisen fetter comes to be; and he knows how the non-arising in the future of the abandoned fetter comes to be.

Perception is considered a mental aggregate, but in the physical body at least, it also requires the physical organs, eyes, brain, etc. Things overlap, so there doesn't have to be absolute delineation between this and that category. Teachings on dependent co-arising say things can't even exist independently, like in the analogy of two sheaves of barley leaning against each other.
"What's the relation between "Consciousness" and "Phenomena (BB); Objects of mind (TNH)"?"

Sitting in meditation, direct your concentration onto the interdependent nature of certain objects. Remember that the subject of knowledge cannot exist independently from the object of knowledge. To see is to see something. To hear is to hear something. To be angry is to be angry about something. Hope is hope for something. Thinking is thinking about something. When the object of knowledge is not present, there can be no subject.
 
Meditate and see the interbeing of the subject and the object. When you practice mindfulness of breathing, then the breathing is mind. When you practice mindfulness of the body, then your body is mind. When you practice mindfulness of objects outside yourself, these objects are mind. Therefore, the contemplation of the interbeing of subject and object is also the contemplation of the mind. Every object of the mind is itself mind. In Buddhism, we call the objects of mind the dharmas.
 
Contemplation on interdependence is a deep looking into all dharmas in order to pierce through to their real nature, in order to see them as part of the great body of reality and in order to see that the great body of reality is indivisible. It cannot be cut into pieces with separate existences of their own.
 
The object of our mind can be a mountain, a rose, the full moon, or the person standing in front of us. We believe these things exist outside of us as separate entities, but these objects of our perceptions are us. This includes our feeling. When we hate someone, we also hate ourself. The object of our mindfulness is actually the whole cosmos. Mindfulness is mindfulness of the body, feelings, perceptions, any of the mental formations, and all of the seeds in our consciousness. The Four Establishments of Mindfulness contain everything in the cosmos. Everything in the cosmos is the object of our perception, and, as such, it does not exist only outside of us but also within us.
-from "The Heart of the Buddha's Teaching", Thich Nhat Hanh


What I think, the so called body is your perception of self. your Ideas of self. Even your breath is idea. breath and body are mental constructions. perceived as Mine.
Hence  Body contemplation is contemplation of sanna only. and In fact when you say kaye kaya-anupassi. means contemplating body as just body. and not proliferating it further. similarly you can do those 7 contemplate. body as anicca,anatta,nirodha etc..
All experience of object and subject are vedana.
all mental construction are dhamma. reflection of internal /external object. your emotion , concepts, ideas, notion of self etc all are dhamma.
faculty of bare awareness. by which you know object as just object. without proliferation is vinnana or citta.
What I understand is that for all practical purpose these understanding is sufficient.
Practically you directly know vedana and dhamma only. Kaya and cita are indirectly known.
